# Fade effect for Silverlight 4 "list"

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'd like a way to display a list of text strings that fades like the following:

[image]

If you're using Office 2010, the effect is used in the new splash screens.

What I'd like is to have the last item selected and all items above faded so we achieve a similar affect.  As items are added, the new item is selected and the previous item moves up and fades away.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could overlay a gradient fill on the first (and I assume last) items in the list.

Comment: Can you provide an example how you'd do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ListBox` to achieve what you want.

In Silverlight 4, there is a new group of states [LayoutStates](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/fluidui/layoutstates.aspx) available within `ListBoxItem` style.

It has three visual states, `AfterLoaded`, `BeforeUnloaded` and `BeforeLoaded`.

> As the names imply, the BeforeLoaded state occurs right before the
>   ListBoxItem is added to the ListBox and the AfterLoaded state happens
>   after the ListBoxItem is added. BeforeUnloaded happens right before the ListBoxItem is removed.

In your case, you need to animate the **fade in** (`Opacity` and `TranslateY`) in the `BeforeLoaded` state when you try to add a new line of text, and animate the **fade out** in the `BeforeUnloaded` state when you try to remove the top line. Below is just one simple example.

```
<Style x:Key="AnimatedListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
...
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="LayoutStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.4" To="BeforeUnloaded">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-37" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualTransition>
        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" />
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="BeforeUnloaded" />
    <VisualState x:Name="BeforeLoaded">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="37" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="1" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="AfterLoaded" />
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Because after you removed the first line, the rest `ListBoxItems` will jump up at once to fill the empty space. To make this transition fluidly, you can overwrite the `ListBox`'s `ItemsPanel` with a normal `StackPanel`, and attach a [FluidMoveBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723946%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to it. Remeber to set the `AppliesTo` to `Children`. This means the animation will happen to the `ListBox`'s children which are the `ListBoxItems`.

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ei:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Hope this helps. :)

**UPDATE**

You use `OpacityMask` to create the fade.

[image]

```
<ScrollViewer Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="180" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0"> 
    <ScrollViewer.OpacityMask> 
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"> 
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0" /> 
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.1" /> 
        </LinearGradientBrush> 
    </ScrollViewer.OpacityMask> 
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <TextBlock Text="First Line" FontSize="14.667"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Second Line" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="14.667"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I wasn't planning on removing items and I don't want the items to fade in and out as they are added or removed. What I want is the list to fade away from bottom to top.  The idea of an overlay seems more consistent.  That said, I'll give your code a try so I can see what you are describing.

Comment: Well, then what's not exactly what the Office 2010 does. If you simply want the overlay, see my updated answer.

Comment: That's not true. Your original suggestion uses animation on the individual items so when removed it will fade from view. The affect I'm looking for and what is used in Office 2010 is that the farther up the list an item goes, the more transparent it becomes. I.e., when the item is one above the last item, it is partly faded and will stay in that state until another item is added. Using animation, the next to last item will fade away completely whether another item is added or not.

Comment: I think your second suggestion is closer to what I'm looking for except that you are hard-coding the two items which is not what I'm looking for.  But I will see if using a ListBox within the ScrollViewer will do the trick.

Comment: You just need to edit the scrollviewer's default style and put the opacitymask in, the listbox already contains a scrollviewer in its style so you don't need to wrap it with another one.